# C# : calling base method from overridden one

Tags: c#, methods, overriding, virtual

With those classes:

```
public abstract class T_BaseClass
{
    public virtual void m_canvas()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("canvas method called from template.");            
    }
}

public class C_ChildT : T_BaseClass
{
    public override void m_canvas()
    {
        base.m_canvas();
        Console.WriteLine("canvas method called from child template.");
    }
}
```

What is the differences between those two implementations?

Difference between

```
C_ChildT mychildclass = new C_ChildT();
```

and

```
T_BaseClass mychildclass1 = new C_ChildT();


mychildclass.m_canvas();
mychildclass1.m_canvas();
```

Hope it looks better M.Skeet.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Calling `base.canevasmethod` *is* how you do it. You already know how to do what you want, so please clarify why you don't want to just use the functionality the language provides for you. This is like asking "how do I override a base class method other than using the override modifier?" (I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions - and if you already do so for production code, please do so for sample code as well. Readability matters just as much for Stack Overflow questions...)

Comment: "and more" - please ask *one* question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you don't need a deep understanding of inheritance to work with it. The minimum, that you should know is that the last child of inheritance sequence methods is called, when you call any method on an object. Also you should know that variable type and object type are different things, and you can store an object of child types in a variable of parent type. So, in your example you have two variables with `C_ChildT` and `T_BaseClass` types. But both objects are `C_ChildT` type. So when you call `m_canvas()` on each of them, you will call the `C_ChildT` implementation of `m_canvas()` in both cases.

Under the hood, when you call a virtual method, your runtime evironment sees, that the method is marked with the `virtual` keyword, so it (runtime environment) starts looking for overrriding of this method in the most derived class. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual).